# Java short circuit confusion

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

This code uses && in the for loop condition. It iterates 4 times resulting in the answer "sum = 20". I would think it iterates 5 times, since the left side of the && condition is true, when the right side becoming false ends the loop.

Basically my question is why does it iterate 4 times and not 5, making the "sum = 30"? Thanks

```
   `int[] lst = {1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int frnt = 0, rear = lst.length - 1;
            frnt < 5 && rear >= 5; frnt++, rear--){
        sum = sum + lst[frnt] + lst[rear];
        System.out.println("frnt: " + frnt);
        System.out.println("rear: " + rear);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(sum);`
```

Comment: && is *and*, which means *both conditions must be true*, and either being false will cause the condition to fail. *This AND that* must both be true.

Comment: I thought 'both conditions must be true' was for &. && is short circuit 'and' which means if the first is true, it does not evaluate the second. That's what I have learned anyways.

Comment: That would be true for || (or). For &&, short circuiting means that if the first is false, it does not evaluate the second because the whole expression is already false.

Comment: THANK YOU @clcto ! Now I understand.

Comment: And thank you @KenWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short circuiting only happens when the value of the whole expression is already known.

For the Logical AND operator (&&) if the left hand side is already false, then it does not matter what the right hand side evaluates to because the whole expression is already false. If the left hand side is true, then the value of the right side determines the value of the expression. Since it is not known until it is evaluated, it must be evaluated.

For the Logical OR operator (||), the reverse is true. If the left side of the expression is true, then it doesn't matter what the right side is, the expression is true, so the right side is not evaluated. If the left side is false, then the value of the expression depends on the right side so it must be evaluated.

Comment: Ah... I mixed up the two ideas. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is originating within the `for` condition. On the last iteration of the loop, both `frnt = 4` and `rear = 4`. The condition `frnt < 5` works, but `rear >= 5` is false, making the entire expression false, which breaks the loop. See below for the variables after each iteration (Note the table shows the variabls after each time the body of the loop has ran and the variables have been modified).

```
              frnt   rear
before loop:  0      8
iteration 1:  1      7
iteration 2:  2      6
iteration 3:  3      5
iteration 4:  4      4 <---- Loop breaks after this
```

The two counters meet in the middle at 4, but the condition specifies that `rear >= 5`. In order to get the correct behavior, change the condition to: `frnt < 5 && rear >= 4`, or more clearly, `frnt <= 4 && rear >= 4`

Answer (score 0):

`frnt`----    `rear`  ----------        `frnt < 5 && rear >= 5`

`0`-----------`8`------------------- `true && true       ->  true`

`1`-----------`7`------------------- `true && true       ->  true`

`2`-----------`6`------------------- `true && true       ->  true`

`3`-----------`5`------------------- `true && true       ->  true`

`4`-----------`4`------------------- `true && false      -> false`

Everything is right, 4 iterations and that's it.

I think you misunderstood the short-circuit principle. In case of && operator the short circuit principle works as follows:

As the result of A && B operation is `true` only in case when both operands are `true` then upon evaluating operand A and discovering that it is `false`, there is no need to evaluate and check the value of operand B. In case when operand A is `true` operand B is always evaluated. So in your case upon the check when the loop breaks the operand A is `4 < 5` and the operand B is `4 >= 5`. So as the operand A is `true` then it is mandatory for operand B to be evaluated and checked and this case is not short circuit as both operands are evaluated. Short circuit case would be the one if operand A is `false` and operand B is not evaluated.